# CXF JAXWS Client Creation error - No Such Method

Tags: java, spring, web-services, client, cxf

I am trying to create a simple cxf client using the flowing snippet in my spring context:

```
<jaxws:client id="cxf_client" serviceClass="com.my.service" address="http://my.service.com/">
    <jaxws:inInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
    </jaxws:inInterceptors>
    <jaxws:outInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
    </jaxws:outInterceptors>
</jaxws:client>
```

However when my server starts I am getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean            with name 'cxf_client': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.common.util.ReflectionUtil.getDeclaredMethod(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;    [Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;
```

Does anyone have any idea what is causing my issue, I am using spring 4.0.5 and CXF 3.0.2.

Cheers

Comment: why your service class "service" starts with lowercase?

Comment: Did you found an answer?